# Set default build agent VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I select what pool (or agent) a CI build uses?  When I select "manage" (next to default queue on the build summary) I see a list of pools, and I have privlegies to create a new pool "laptops" but no way to select this as the default. It always ends up in "Hosted" (and the net core .csproj is not supported there yet)

Larsi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of clicking "Manage" next to "Default" on the Summary tab you should be able to change the default agent queue for the build definition by following these steps:

1. On the Build Definition summary view, click on Edit (to the right of the Queue new build...)
2. When the build step list is displayed, select the General tab
   [image]
3. Now you can change the Default Agent Queue from the drop down
   [image]

Comment: How could I miss that? Thanks

Comment: In newer versions, this seems to be under "Options" to the right hand panel.

Comment: It's moved again! Now the build agent is on the "Tasks" tab, select "Build Process", the first item on the task list.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the location in the 2017 UI of team services.

[image]

Comment: you can select image to be show in answer by selecting valid formatting option.